# My Putty logfile plot using matplotlib plt.draw is all wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some temperature readings live, 2 readings per second, using an open logfile. It works but it keeps starting over and I don't know why. For example, if the logData file starts with twenty 85 degree readings then fifty 84 degree readings, the plot should look like a two level stair step. And the bottom step should be 2.5 times longer than the first step. But what I get is a too long first step, then a very short second step (only about 5% of what it should be), then it plots the first temp again (correct length this time), then the second step again but a little longer (about 20% of what it should be). It keeps repeating this tooth like pattern, with each bottom step getting closer to the correct length. Any suggestions?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tempF=[]
plt.ion()
while True:
    lines = open('putty.log').readlines()
    open('logData.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[10:-1])#The 10:-1 is to remove junk from putty's opening lines in putty.log
    with open('logData.txt') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            p=line.split(' ')
            temp = float(p[1])
            tempF.append(temp)
            plt.plot(tempF, 'ro-') 
            plt.draw()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not wrong at all. You are reading and writing it all wrong.

So here's the deal. `with open` statement keeps reopening your file and sets you on the beginning of it. Each time python does its roundabout trip through the loop, it reads the file from the start, even if it hasn't changed yet, and puts the value in a list. If you test this code on just a single line file, you'd see it keeps adding that same line into your array despite it already read it. Then you plot the whole list the same number of times as your file is long. It would be enough to plot the list just once, once you read in all the new lines.

Issue is also that you keep reading all the lines from `putty.log` and writing all the lines to `logData.txt`, and the reading all the lines from `logData.txt` to a list, but you never reset the list. This looks like it could lead to doubling your data constantly. I.e.

```
putty: 10
log: 10
templ.append(10) --> [10]

putty: 10, 10
log: 10, 10 #because you use the "w" 
#but you forget to forget about old numbers in the templ

templ.append(10)
templ.append(10) ---> [10, 10, 10] #instead of [10, 10]
```

While on the subject, using the `w` option was either smart or lucky. `w` will overwrite all previous entries in the files, and write a completely just the new ones. This guarantees you that at least you're not doubling your results in the `logData` file.

Python possibly also clashes with putty for rights over the file at which point putty probably gets denied access and your script keeps reading in the same value, if it doesn't you were probably in luck because you have the command one-lined so its relatively fast, closes the file and hasn't failed so far.

So the solution could be that you forget all data each time you start from the top and read all of them to a fresh list. This prevents doubling the data. You also don't really need to save the `putty.log` to a different file once you have readlines, you can just use them.

Use a new `while` with a try-catch block that will ask if opening the file failed, and will keep trying until it opens the file, quickly save the readlines to a list, and close the file again.

To wait use the `time` built in module and `time.sleep(n_seconds)` . I'd recommend waiting for longer periods of time (longer than 0.5 seconds, ~3-5 seconds), to ensure matplotlib doesn't crash, this can be done without any resolution loss because the `putty.log` will remember all the values (minus possibly maybe the ones that he didn't manage to write while you did your `readlines`).